# Web Services and cookie handling

Tags: asp.net, cookies, webmethod, forwarding

There's an web service and it depends on the *cookies* sent by the browser for its operations. The service works fine as long as it is being accessed by a browser, but fails when it is accessed by another service or program.

The aspx file that I want to introduce in step 2.a has full access to the original cookies. I need a way so that the cookies in 2.a are forwarded in step 2.b

(step 3 is not required after 2.a and 2.b are developed )

Thanks
[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First, get the cookies to your C# code, somehow.

Second, use the [CookieContainer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.httpwebclientprotocol.cookiecontainer.aspx) property of your web service proxy to set the cookies to use.